# React State stays null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having a bug that even when state was set, it stays null in the loadNextPage function.
I am setting the state here

```
useEffect(() => {
        const cachedData = localStorage.getItem("cachedPokemons");
        const cachedNextPageUrl = localStorage.getItem("nextPageUrl");

        if (cachedData) {
            setPokemons(JSON.parse(cachedData));
        }
        
        if (cachedNextPageUrl) {
            setNextPageUrl(cachedNextPageUrl);
        }

        if (!cachedData || !cachedNextPageUrl) {
            // If no cached data or nextPageUrl, fetch from the API and cache it
            fetchInitialData();
        }
    }, []);
```

` const handleScroll = () => {
// Check if the user has scrolled to the bottom
if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
loadNextPage(); // Load the next page of Pokémon
}
};

```
const fetchInitialData = async () => {
    let apiUrl = API_BASE_URL + '/api/pokemons';
    let response = await fetch(apiUrl); 
    let data = await response.json();
    let pokemonList = data.results;

    setPokemons(pokemonList);
    setNextPageUrl(data.next);

    // Cache the initial data and next page URL
    localStorage.setItem("cachedPokemons", JSON.stringify(pokemonList));
    localStorage.setItem("nextPageUrl", data.next);
};

const loadNextPage = async () => {
    console.log("Next page URL:", nextPageUrl);

    if (nextPageUrl) {
        let response = await fetch(nextPageUrl);
        let data = await response.json();
        let pokemonList = data.results;

        // Use the functional update to access the latest state
        setPokemons((prevPokemons) => [...prevPokemons, ...pokemonList]);
        setNextPageUrl(data.next);
    }
};`
```